# How do I convert a column full of "Records" to just one column full of one value?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Hey I am working on a project that contains a column that contains only records. Each record has a row labeled "Amount" and row labeled "Currency". The row "Amount" has the value I need and "Currency" is just has the value Null. How do I convert this column of records with just the value for "Amount"? Below is what I am talking about.

Below is a picture of the column filled with records

[image]

[image]

Above is a picture of opening up the first record when you click on it

I just need that value for "Amount" not for "Currency". What would be the best way to convert this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps below:

1. Click on the icon just besides the 'Amount' column as shown by blue arrow in the screenshot below.
   [image]
2. Then, you will get a dialogue box as shown in the screenshot below listing your fields
   **amount** and **currency**.
   [image]

3. As you want only amount, uncheck the box for currency and hit OK. This should get you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a custom column with formula

```
 =Record.Field([Amount],"amount")
```